# Redio button valur fetch in yii2

Tags: mysql, forms, yii2

in yii2 i used redio list

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'status')->radioList(array('0'=>'Allocate',1=>'aval')); ?>
```

In database in store 0 or 1 but in grideview how to fetch Allocate or avl tag ??
please help me .

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for status column:

```
[
'attribute'=>'status',
'class' => '\kartik\grid\DataColumn',
'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'text-align:center'],
'filter'=>['0'=>'Allocate',1=>'aval'], // filter
'value'=>function($model)
{
 if($model->status=='0')
 {
   return 'Allocate';
 }
 else
 {
 return 'Aval';
 }
}
],
```